# How to achieve MySQL Clustered Index-Ordered Join Result

Tags: php, mysql, join, clustered-index

Suppose I have two tables, **table1** with two fields: **id and cost**, with a clustered, primary, index on **(cost, id)**. The other table, **table2**, just has id, and that is the primary key.

Thus, the data in table1 is ordered by cost - due to the clustered index.

If I go:

```
Select * from table1 join table2 using (id)
```

the results aren't always going to be in the order that the clustered-index in table1 defines. In that case, how would one achieve this kind of ordering when joining multiple tables to a table with a specific/composite clustered index?

Comment: Please be careful.  SQL result set ordering is *formally unpredictable* unless you include an `ORDER BY` clause in your query. *Formally unpredictable* is worse than random, because it's harder to catch in testing: the order of the result set stays the same **until it doesn't.**  `ORDER BY` doesn't cost much when your index order matches it.

Comment: To order a resultset, you have to use `order by`. If you don't use an `order by` it will result in an arbitrary order - which can be the order you currently hope for, but which is not at all guranteed, and might change at any point (e.g. when mysql chooses a different execution plan, which is the effect that `straight_join` had here.)

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is a STRIAGHT_JOIN.

If you do:

```
SELECT * from table1 STRIAGHT_JOIN table2 using (id)
```

the order will be preserved.